# R programming: Linear Equation

Tags: r

How can I state, in R code, a list of certain possible values for a given equation? For example (this is just a random equation feel free to use any formula suitable):

> For positive integers a, b, and c with the formula x^3 + y^2 = z.

How can I test for all possible combinations of x and y less than or equal to 1000 and c to satisfy the formula and check if the variables are also valid inputs?

Answer (score 4):

You can generate all possible values with `expand.grid` and then subset to the ones meeting your criteria:

```
vals <- expand.grid(x=seq(1000), y=seq(1000))
subset(vals, x^3 + y^2 == 108)
#      x  y
# 8003 3  9
# 9002 2 10
```

Comment: is there a way I can implement this with control flow construction statements (if for while)?

Comment: @12341234 In general for and while loops are not the best choices in R. In your case the reason is clear: if you needed to accumulate many combinations meeting your criteria in a for loop, you'd likely grow an object containing results one-by-one, which is inefficient in R. I would suggest you embrace R idioms when using R instead of trying to force the idioms of other languages.

Comment: I am well aware of that (hence my question) since vectorisation is quicker in terms of effeciency. I just realised but my comment is  supposed to ask if I can implement it without control structures??

Comment: @12341234 sorry, then I don't understand your original comment. There if no `if`, `for`, or `while` in this solution. All it's doing is subsetting based on a logical expression.